# Variable length argument list with default argument?

Tags: scala, arguments

Is it possible to set a default argument for a variable length argument list ?

Example:

```
def foo(args: String*) = args.foreach(println)
```

How to set a default argument for `args` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  If you try, the compiler will tell you:

> error: a parameter section with a `*'-parameter is not allowed to have default arguments

But you can achieve the same result with method overloading:

```
class A {
  def foo(args: String*): Unit = args.foreach(println)
  def foo(): Unit = foo("A", "B", "C")
}
```

Here's when you provide arguments:

```
scala> (new A).foo("A", "B")
A
B
```

And here's the "default":

```
scala> (new A).foo()
A
B
C
```